# How Can I PXE Boot to an CentOS 7 Instance Installed to an iSCSI Lun?

Tags: centos, redhat, iscsi

I've successfully installed CentOS 7 to an iSCSI LUN.  How must I configure my PXE server to boot to this newly installed iSCSI LUN?

Comment: do you mean your DHCP server?

Answer (score 5):

Here's a guidance that should be useful for you: http://it-joe.com/linux/iscsi_pxe_boot

I've done the same with RHEL installation using StarWind as iSCSI server.

Comment: Really useful topic, I'll save it as a bookmark.